# Packet Loss between server-to-server Oracle Linux 7.9 bond

Tags: linux, oracle, bonding, packetloss

I have 2 Oracle Linux 7.9 physical servers, each one with a dual nic. I bonded this dual nic end attached server-to-server with 2 cables (not crossover cables). I have packet loss in average 50% pinging between them. What is missing?

nic1 server 1:

```
HWADDR=b4:96:91:6f:84:7c
NAME="team1 slave 1"
UUID=c06add74-c881-4b23-b47b-d1c0eff0bd53
DEVICE=p2p1
ONBOOT=yes
TEAM_MASTER=team1
DEVICETYPE=TeamPort
```

nic2 server1:

```
HWADDR=b4:96:91:6f:84:7d
NAME="team1 slave 2"
UUID=8065b2ba-dd97-4fb9-8be9-853f7075db22
DEVICE=p2p2
ONBOOT=yes
TEAM_MASTER=team1
DEVICETYPE=TeamPort
```

bond on server1:

```
DEVICE=team1
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=172.16.127.31
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=172.16.127.253
DNS1=10.3.3.1
DNS2=10.3.3.2
DEFROUTE=no
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=no
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_PRIVACY=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME="Team connection 2"
ONBOOT=yes
DEVICETYPE=Team
TYPE=Ethernet
```

ifconfig results on server 1:

```
team1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.127.31  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.127.255
        inet6 fe80::b696:91ff:fe6f:847c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b4:96:91:6f:84:7c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1969136631  bytes 1103513127863 (1.0 TiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2152731904  bytes 1449233573392 (1.3 TiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 3960657 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

lsmod results on server 1:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
oracleacfs           5140480  2
oracleadvm            819200  8
oracleoks             651264  2 oracleacfs,oracleadvm
oracleafd             212992  1
rds_tcp                24576  0
rds                   266240  1 rds_tcp
dm_service_time        16384  10
iscsi_tcp              20480  44
libiscsi_tcp           28672  1 iscsi_tcp
libiscsi               65536  2 libiscsi_tcp,iscsi_tcp
scsi_transport_iscsi   118784  4 libiscsi_tcp,iscsi_tcp,libiscsi
team_mode_roundrobin    16384  2
team                   40960  1 team_mode_roundrobin
ipmi_ssif              24576  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             172032  0
kvm                   524288  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
dcdbas                 16384  0
aesni_intel           172032  0
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
sg                     45056  0
pcspkr                 16384  0
shpchp                 40960  0
wmi                    20480  0
ipmi_si                57344  0
ipmi_msghandler        49152  2 ipmi_ssif,ipmi_si
acpi_cpufreq           20480  0
acpi_pad              180224  0
acpi_power_meter       20480  0
dm_multipath           24576  11 dm_service_time
binfmt_misc            20480  1
auth_rpcgss            61440  0
sunrpc                348160  5 auth_rpcgss
ip_tables              28672  0
xfs                  1073152  4
libcrc32c              16384  1 xfs
sd_mod                 45056  23
crc32c_intel           24576  17
igb                   208896  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 igb
i2c_core               61440  3 igb,ipmi_ssif,i2c_algo_bit
dca                    16384  1 igb
i40e                  335872  0
ahci                   36864  2
libahci                32768  1 ahci
ptp                    20480  2 igb,i40e
megaraid_sas          147456  0
libata                245760  2 ahci,libahci
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
dm_mirror              24576  0
dm_region_hash         24576  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 20480  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
dm_mod                110592  76 dm_multipath,dm_log,dm_mirror
```

nic1 server 2:

```
HWADDR=b4:96:91:6f:86:be
NAME="team1 slave 1"
UUID=8ae2ca08-5dd3-4fd7-aa02-1b769924179b
DEVICE=p2p1
ONBOOT=yes
TEAM_MASTER=team1
DEVICETYPE=TeamPort
```

nic2 server 2:

```
HWADDR=b4:96:91:6f:86:bf
NAME="team1 slave 2"
UUID=2a809c7d-72e2-4cf3-9aa7-33e908d6f8ca
DEVICE=p2p2
ONBOOT=yes
TEAM_MASTER=team1
DEVICETYPE=TeamPort
```

bond on server 2:

```
DEVICE=team1
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=172.16.127.32
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=172.16.127.253
DNS1=10.3.3.1
DNS2=10.3.3.2
DEFROUTE=no
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=no
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_PRIVACY=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME="Team connection 2"
ONBOOT=yes
DEVICETYPE=Team
TYPE=Ethernet
```

ifconfig results on server 2:

```
team1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.127.32  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.127.255
        inet6 fe80::b696:91ff:fe6f:86be  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b4:96:91:6f:86:be  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2152737672  bytes 1419102570404 (1.2 TiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1967430604  bytes 1130980690912 (1.0 TiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

lsmod results on server 2:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
oracleacfs           5140480  0
oracleadvm            819200  0
oracleoks             651264  2 oracleacfs,oracleadvm
oracleafd             212992  0
dm_service_time        16384  10
iscsi_tcp              20480  44
libiscsi_tcp           28672  1 iscsi_tcp
libiscsi               65536  2 libiscsi_tcp,iscsi_tcp
scsi_transport_iscsi   118784  4 libiscsi_tcp,iscsi_tcp,libiscsi
team_mode_roundrobin    16384  2
team                   40960  1 team_mode_roundrobin
ipmi_ssif              24576  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             172032  0
kvm                   524288  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
sg                     45056  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           172032  0
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
dcdbas                 16384  0
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
pcspkr                 16384  0
shpchp                 40960  0
wmi                    20480  0
ipmi_si                57344  0
ipmi_msghandler        49152  2 ipmi_ssif,ipmi_si
acpi_cpufreq           20480  0
acpi_pad              180224  0
acpi_power_meter       20480  0
dm_multipath           24576  11 dm_service_time
binfmt_misc            20480  1
auth_rpcgss            61440  0
sunrpc                348160  5 auth_rpcgss
ip_tables              28672  0
xfs                  1073152  4
libcrc32c              16384  1 xfs
sd_mod                 45056  23
crc32c_intel           24576  17
igb                   208896  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 igb
i2c_core               61440  3 igb,ipmi_ssif,i2c_algo_bit
dca                    16384  1 igb
i40e                  335872  0
ahci                   36864  2
libahci                32768  1 ahci
ptp                    20480  2 igb,i40e
megaraid_sas          147456  0
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
libata                245760  2 ahci,libahci
dm_mirror              24576  0
dm_region_hash         24576  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 20480  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
dm_mod                110592  74 dm_multipath,dm_log,dm_mirror
```